# Is there a tool to get .net core process metrics?

Tags: .net-core, process-explorer

Process Explorer is very good, but it does not show metrics for .net core processes.
Is there a tool to connect to arbitrary .net core process and get metrics # GC collections, GC heaps sizes, time in GC, and the like.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20331#issuecomment-304322726

Comment: https://github.com/sebastienros/memoryleak/blob/master/src/MemoryLeak/MemoryLeak/Controllers/DiagnosticsController.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dotnet-counters monitor -n <YourAppName>
```

Get it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters